# Feature Selection for Supervised Learning

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
```

I have 3 labels (male, female, na), denoted as follows:

```
labels = [0,1,2]
```

Each label was defined by 3 features (height, weight, and age) as the training data:

Training data for males:

```
male_height = np.array([111,121,137,143,157])
male_weight = np.array([60,70,88,99,75])
male_age = np.array([41,32,73,54,35])

males = np.vstack([male_height,male_weight,male_age]).T
```

Training data for females:

```
female_height = np.array([91,121,135,98,90])
female_weight = np.array([32,67,98,86,56])
female_age = np.array([51,35,33,67,61])

females = np.vstack([female_height,female_weight,female_age]).T
```

Training data for not availables:

```
na_height = np.array([96,127,145,99,91])
na_weight = np.array([42,97,78,76,86])
na_age = np.array([56,35,49,64,66])

nas = np.vstack([na_height,na_weight,na_age]).T
```

So, the complete training data are:

```
trainingData = np.vstack([males,females,nas])
```

Complete labels are:

```
labels =  np.repeat(labels,5)
```

Now, I want to select the best features, output their names, and apply only those best features for  fitting the support vector machine model.

I tried below according to the answer from @eickenberg and the comments from @larsmans

```
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=keep)
clf = make_pipeline(selector, StandardScaler(), svm.SVC())
clf.fit(trainingData, labels)

selected = trainingData[selector.get_support()]

print selected

[[111 60 41]
 [121 70 32]]
```

However, all the selected elements belongs to the label 'male' with the features: height, weight, and age respectively. I could not figure out where I am messing up? Could someone guide me into right direction?

Comment: You're using the support to select samples instead of features. To actually select features, do `selector.transform(trainingData)`. To inspect the features, do `np.array(["height", "weight", "age"])[selector.get_support()]` as @eickenberg recommends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use e.g. `SelectKBest` as follows

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest, f_classif
keep = 2
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=keep)
```

and place it into your pipeline

```
pipe = make_pipeline(selector, StandardScaler(), svm.SVC())

pipe.fit(trainingData, labels)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how can I know which features were selected. I want to output their names.

Comment: `selector.get_support` returns a boolean mask corresponding to the selected features.

Comment: @larsmans 'print trainingData[selector.get_support()]' gives AttributeError: 'SelectKBest' object has no attribute 'scores_'

Comment: @bercik Did you `fit` it?

Comment: @larsmans sorry, yes after fitting it produces the '[[111  60  41]
 [121  70  32]]'. But I could not understand what does this mean? I want to know the feature names (e.g., height, weight, age) which were selected during fitting.

Comment: `get_support` returns booleans that indicate whether features will be selected or not. It doesn't know about feature names, only column positions.

Comment: @larsmans My question was 'how to select the features?' So I want  to know which features are best.

Comment: The ones listed as `True` in `get_support`. Or look at the `scores_` on `selector` to get a ranking. You need to record the names separately.

Comment: @larsmans HERE the selector.get_support produced '[[111 60 41] [121 70 32]]'. All the elements in this array belongs to the label 'male' with the features: height, weight, and age respectively. So, it means only the features of male are able to predict the other labels: females, and nas as well? Could you please make sense to me?

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with how you are doing this exactly? The support should clearly indicate a certain subset of 3 features, which is not happening here. Also, looking at the code you posted, your labels do not seem to correspond with the way you construct your example.

Comment: OK, based on your update it is possible to see what is happening: You probably want to be doing `selected = np.array(["height", "weight", "age"])[selector.get_support()]`. Or to directly select the data of interest, `selected_columns = trainingData[:, selector.get_support()]`

Comment: @eickenberg The latter expression is just `selector.transform(trainingData)`.

Comment: @larsmans good point and the canonical way to do it. I started with `trainingData[selector.get_support()]` in mind and the minimal correction was to change the selection axis :)

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, I have used the Support Vector Machine Model on text classification (which is an entirely different problem altogether). But, through that experience, I can confidently say that the more features you have, the better your predictions will be.

To summarize, do not filter out the features that are most important because the Support Vector Machine will make use of features no matter how little importance.

But, if this is a huge necessity, look into scikit learn's [Random Forest Classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier). It can accurately assess which features are more important, using the "feature_importances_" attribute.

Here's an example of how I would use it (code not tested):

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier() #tweak the parameters yourself
clf.fit(X,Y) #if you're passing in a sparse matrix, apply .toarray() to X
print clf.feature_importances_
```

Hope that helps.